# Response.Redirect not working for only one page, the rest work correctly

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, https

For some reason my one c# page will not redirect to another page after form submission. Response.Redirect() works on every other page except for this one. I have no understanding of why. I followed through the entire debugging and it loads all the information for the other page but just does not transfers. Here is the set-up of my page structure. I have tried deleting the cache and following the traffic on fiddler and everything seems normal. Anyone have any ideas?

https://pastebin.com/B57X0Phu - The entire c# for that page.

https://pastebin.com/cJbYYGP2 - The entire asp.net page

https://pastebin.com/ZUdHMwg4 - The Javascript file that sends the data to the c# page.

```
protected void AddMealButton_Click(MealFoodViewModel addmealFormHttpRequest)
    {
        int mealID = 0;
        string addmealFormHttpRequestString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(addmealFormHttpRequest);

        using (HttpClient client = CreateClient())
        {
            HttpResponseMessage response = client.PostAsJsonAsync("api/Meals", addmealFormHttpRequestString).Result;

            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                string foodstring = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
                Meal mealView = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Meal>(foodstring); ;
                mealID = mealView.MealID;
            }
            else
            {
                ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "script", "ErrorHandler();", true);
            }
        }

        using (HttpClient client = CreateClient())
        {
            HttpResponseMessage response = client.PostAsJsonAsync("api/MealFoods/" + mealID, addmealFormHttpRequestString).Result;

            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                if (Response.IsClientConnected)
                {
                    Response.Redirect("~/mealplanner.aspx", false); //Where it redirects. It gives me no errors
                }
                else
                {
                    Response.End();
                    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "script", "ErrorHandler();", true);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "script", "ErrorHandler();", true);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is as unclear as it gets, there is a reported issue stating that response.redirect is just not working at cases.

alot of people reported bugs on it, even on asp.net official forums and some states that restarting the VS and giving it a go might work.

Some stated they tried `Server.Transfer()` which I do not prefer as it is not the proper solution, I did not want to do A `Server.Transfer()` but well then...

The main point here is that there are alot of bugs regarding this, the easiest and fastest solution is to use client side:

```
window.location = 'location'
```

OR:

```
// similar behavior as an HTTP redirect
window.location.replace("http://sidanmor.com");
```

OR:

```
// similar behavior as clicking on a link
window.location.href = "http://sidanmor.com";
```

Comment: I mean, I guess I could use client side. It just puzzles  me that it is just this file that does it.